# Bug doesn't have tag formatting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, new-nav

The [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) does not have the required-tag meta styling:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Please make it the required-tag styling, like this: [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), not [discusion](/questions/tagged/discusion).

It also has the same issue with the mod tags. They show as [statvs-completed](/questions/tagged/statvs-completed), not [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning that the mod-only tags don't either - basically there's no extra CSS for *any* of those tags!

Comment: Not a bug actually, that's the way it always was. Favorite tags do not have the special formatting, you can verify on sites with the old navigation.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well not a [tag:new-nav] bug. But still a bug.

Comment: I don't see this; I see bug **in grey**. The first post in your screenshot has the correct styling too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's more easy to see the difference with moderator tags e.g. the various status-* tags.

Comment: @Tim well, since the focus is on the new navigation, chances are low they will fix an unrelated bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been completed and deployed with new nav alpha 2.